# Deleting hyperlink text from Excel text

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Is there a formula/built in feature for excel where I can remove anything that starts with an "http" in a row of text? They could be anywhere in the text as well. As an example,

Say I have "John went to the park http\centeralpark.com and ate a hot dog https\hotdog.com that he liked very much"

So what I would want here is the text with no links:

"John went to the park and ate a hot dog that he liked very much"

Any easy way to use this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide an example. Where is the text stored? In a cell or in a textfield?

Comment: It's all just in a cell, Say "A:1"

Comment: So then I recommend VBA if you really want to remove the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a VBA function to remove all instances of your hyperlink:

Formula:

> =RemoveHyperlink(A1)

[image]

Code:

```
Public Function RemoveHyperlink(ByVal value1 As String) As String
    Do While InStr(value1, "http") > 0 And InStr(value1, ".com") > InStr(value1, "http")
        value1 = Left(value1, InStr(value1, "http") - 1) & Mid(value1, InStr(value1, ".com") + 5)
    Loop
    RemoveHyperlink = value1
End Function
```

Comment: 'This works well but can it be modified for links that don't end in ".com"? Basically I just want to delete anything after the "http", keeping in mind links can appear in the middle of two sentences.

Comment: No worries, let me know if you need help and I will modify it for you.